# How to programmatically select list (text) field in Drupal 8?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, content-management-system, drupal-8

I have successfully created node programmatically using Drupal 8 Node::create and be able to select list (integer) field correctly as following, but list (text) field is not getting selected with the same process. Any help appreciated.

## (Manage Fields)

```
LABEL   MACHINE NAME    FIELD TYPE
===========================

    Expires (in Days)   field_expires_in_days_  List (integer) -> NOT WORKING
    Item Type   field_item_type List (text) - Working
```

## Allowed value list for 'field_expires_in_days_

```
30|30
60|60
90|90
```

## Allowed value list for 'field_item_type'

```
tipsheet|Tip Sheet
fyi|FYI
video|Video
```

## (Controller)

```
$newListItem = array(); //prepare new item
$newListItem["title"] = "Title 111";
$newListItem["summary"] = "Some description";
$newListItem["itemType"] = "tipsheet";
$newListItem["expiresInDays"] = "30";

$node = Node::create([
'type' => 'custom_content_type',
'status' => 1,
'title' => $listItem['title'],
'body' => $listItem['summary'],
'field_item_type ' => $listItem['itemType'],
'field_expires_in_days_' => $listItem['expiresInDays'],
]);
$node->save();
```

https://www.drupal.org/node/2650648

Answer (score 1):

there is a space in key '**field_item_type** '

Comment: OMG...that was amazing find... i was using Notepad++ which didn't seems to find that... is there any IDE or code editor that you recommend for PHP or specially for Drupal?

Comment: PHPStorm, best, but you have to pay. netbean is free, but not as good as PHPstorm